# LPAD in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't see a function like `LPAD` in SQL Server 2008. For example how can I convert the following queries into T-SQL?

```
select  LPAD(MY_VALUE,2,' ')) VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Comment: Be aware that if you are trying to replicate the LPAD function from Oracle, none of the answers below are correct for the case where the output length is less than the input length.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Basically pad it with the number of characters you are intending to select and then right the string.

```
Select right(replicate(' ',2) + YourFieldValue,2) from YourTable
```

You can use the space function instead of replicate, space(number_of_spaces), replicate just allows you to pad with alternative characters.

Comment: this gets the characters from the right.forexample i want to get 18 from 18.00.This returns 00

Comment: Your question asked about LPAD, select LPAD('ab',5,'x') from dual gives xxxab, e.g. it pads the left to the required amount - mimicced that in SQL Server. Technically your PLSQL is invalid due to bracketting as well, so you might of missed something.

Answer (score 5):

Manual calculations can be annoying to apply inside queries. Luckily, we can create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LPAD
(
    @string VARCHAR(MAX), -- Initial string
    @length INT,          -- Size of final string
    @pad CHAR             -- Pad character
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLICATE(@pad, @length - LEN(@string)) + @string;
END
GO
```

*(Please replace `VARCHAR` with `NVARCHAR` to your liking, or use an alternative algorithm.)*

Then:

```
SELECT dbo.LPAD(MY_VALUE, 2, ' ') VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Should work [since SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174383%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I needed something similar but I couldn't use '+' because then it was interpreted as an addition between the numbers '0000000000' and [seq_no]. So I used concat instead and it worked fine.

```
select right (concat(replicate('0', 10),  next value for seq_no), 10);
```

Comment: You can also `CAST(your_number AS VARCHAR(10))` and work with strings

Answer (score 4):

I've come up with a LPAD and RPAD function where you can use a characterstring for the pad-part.

They should work the same as the DB2 versions.

Here's the LPAD:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LPAD
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Initial string
    @length INT,           -- Size of final string
    @pad NVARCHAR(MAX)     -- Pad string
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SUBSTRING(REPLICATE(@pad, @length),1,@length - LEN(@string)) + @string;
END
GO
```

And here is the RPAD:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RPAD
(
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), -- Initial string
    @length INT,           -- Size of final string
    @pad NVARCHAR(MAX)     -- Pad string
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @string + SUBSTRING(REPLICATE(@pad, @length),1,@length - LEN(@string));
END
GO
```