# Add 0 at beginning in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have small table

```
Create Table TestDates
(
  TestDateId int identity (1,1),
  RunDateTime DateTime
)
```

I manage to execute distinct query that brings only time but 
if hour or minute is less then 10 I want to add zero

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 13, 2) + ':'
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 16, 2) + ' '
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 18, 2) AS DistinctDate
from TestDates
```

See example

```
**Current Output     Desired Output**

8:1 PM               **08:01 PM** 
8:33 AM              **08:33 AM**
```

I tried to use right function but it does not help

```
SELECT DISTINCT Right('00' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 13, 2),2) + ':'
+ Right('00' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 16, 2),2) + ' '
+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 18, 2) AS DistinctDate
from TestDates
```

Please advice

Comment: DUPlicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I tried to use Right but it does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     Right('00'+LTRIM(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 13, 2)),2) + 
     ':'
     + Right('00' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 16, 2),2) + ' '
     + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, RunDateTime, 100), 18, 2) AS DistinctDate
FROM TestDates
```

The problem is that the first substring returns _8 (space 8), so you need to trim the value to get rid of the space, then do you adding 00 code.

Answer (score 1):

Create this function and wrap any datetime field you want to apply it to. Example usage:

```
SELECT TestDateId,dbo.ProperHours(RunDateTime) FROM TestDates
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ProperHours(
    @Time DATETIME
)
RETURNS CHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Hours TINYINT
    DECLARE @Minutes TINYINT
    DECLARE @HoursAsString CHAR(2)
    DECLARE @MinutesAsString CHAR(2)
    DECLARE @AmPm CHAR(2)

    SELECT  @Hours=DATEPART(hh,@Time),
            @Minutes=DATEPART(n,@Time),
            @AmPm=CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(hh,@Time)>=12 THEN 'PM'
                    ELSE 'AM'
                END

    IF @Hours>12
        BEGIN
            SET @Hours=@Hours-12
        END
    ELSE IF @Hours=0
        BEGIN
            SET @Hours=12
        END

    SELECT  @HoursAsString=CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Hours),
            @MinutesAsString=CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Minutes)

    IF LEN(@HoursAsString)=1
        BEGIN
            SET @HoursAsString = '0' + @HoursAsString
        END

    IF LEN(@MinutesAsString)=1
        BEGIN
            SET @MinutesAsString = '0' + @MinutesAsString
        END

    RETURN @HoursAsString + ':' + @MinutesAsString + ' ' + @AmPm
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Replace(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(100), RunDateTime,131), 12, 5), ' ', '0') 
  + ' ' 
  + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(100), RunDateTime,131), 24, 2)
from TestDates
```