# How to Update length Automatically

Tags: sql

From a table I am getting the length of character in a column. My query is below

```
SELECT b.[file_id],b.[lineno],b.fileContent, datalength(b.fileContent) Length1
FROM FileBascContent b join filebasic on filebasic.[file_id]=b.[file_id]
WHERE substring(b.fileContent,1,4)
 NOT IN ('VOL1','HDR1','UHL1','UTL1','HDR2','EOF1','EOF2') 
AND filebasic.[file_id]=347
```

I am getting the result 98, 97 and 100 which is fine for me.

Is there any way which will add space 2 or 3 and the length will be 100. Which I want is that all the length which are not 100, should be hundred.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I think the OP wants to pad the strings (left or right?) with spaces - so they are all 100 characters in length.

Comment: Which database system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but you probably need something like [LPAD function on Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm). Here is question about doing it on SQL Server: [LPAD in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean  this?

```
Right(Space(100) + b.fileContent,100) fileContent
```