# Format date where the position of the parts is variable

Tags: sql, datetime

We have a file that needs to be imported that has dates in it. The dates are in a format that I have not seen before and the day part can vary in length (but not the month or year seemingly) and position based on wether the number is double digit or not, i.e.

Dates:

```
13082014 is 13th February 2014

9092013 is 9th September 2013
```

The current script tries to substring the parts out, but fails on the second one as there is not enough data. I could write an if or case to check the length, but is there a SQL format that can be used to reliably import this data?

To clarify this is MSSQL and the date format is ddmmyyyy or dmmyyyy

Comment: What DBMS are you using? They differ very much when it comes to date and string functions.

Comment: Is the month component always two digits (as per your second example `09`)?  If not, you will have some difficulty parsing this correctly.  If it is always two digits then the month is always the substring of the string length minus 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPAD a zero when it is missing so to always get an eight character date string. Here is an example with Oracle, other DBMS may have other string and date functions to achieve the same.

```
select to_date(datestring, 'ddmmyyyy')
from
(
  select lpad('13082014', 8, '0') as datestring from dual
  union all
  select lpad('9092013', 8, '0') as datestring from dual
);
```

Result:

```
13.08.2014
09.09.2013
```

Comment: Used the answer here to get the SQL version of LPAD, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008, `right(replicate('0', 8) + dbo.StudentsRaw.DatePassed, 8)`

Answer (score 2):

One of the simple way is using STUFF.

example:

```
select STUFF(STUFF('13082014 ',3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'); 
//result: 13/08/2014
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the dates to a relevant date format then import data(based on the dateformat change the logic).
something like this :

```
select Convert(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,YourDateColumn,106),103)
```