# Adding the value in column of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I need to add two zero in POS data to make it 14th character numbers because TV UPC has 14th character numbers UPC.

For example

**Table 1**

```
POS UPC 
------------
123456789012
```

**Table 2**

```
TV UPC
--------------
00123456789012
```

I have to make it POS UPC 14 character number by adding two zero at the beginning of the number to compare exact match.

Comment: `RIGHT('0000000000000' + <column>, 14)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [LPAD in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: If it's a number, why are you storing it as text? Storing it as a number would prevent issues like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the number with 14 `0`s and select 14 characters from right which will give you desired output

```
DECLARE @Number varchar(100)='123456789012'

SELECT RIGHT('00000000000000'+@Number,14)
```

Output

```
00123456789012
```

Replace variable with your column name.

Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f1d32/1

Comment: Thank you, Dark Knight. Actually I need to give more detail about my question. I need to add two zeros at left for 500 records or Columns with a single syntax.