# Concatenate 2 x fields to make a Date

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 x fields T1.period and T1.year both have data type smallint
Using SQL Management Studio 2014 how may I Concatenate them AND return result as a DATE type?

Also, T1.period has values 1 to 12 how may I pad this out to 01 to 12 ... or will changing to date type sort this out?

Much appreciated!

Sample data ...

period  yr
1   2015
2   2009
12  2009
11  2010
10  2011

Result will be ...
Date
01/01/2015
01/02/2009
01/12/2009
01/11/2010
01/10/2011

Thanks!

Looks terrible struggling to get it into lists - sorry :(

Comment: please show some sample data with expected results

Comment: Hi
I am unsure of the syntax so need help with that area - thanks!

Comment: please post some sample values from fields and what should be the final output based on them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a date with T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql)

Comment: You could use `RIGHT(0 + CONVERT(varchar(2), T1.period), 2)` for the padding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912416/lpad-in-sql-server-2008 For LPAD .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Converting Your Values The Old Fashioned Way**

Assuming that your `t1.period` value actually just represents a month, you could consider just converting your values to strings and then converting that concatenated result into a date via the [`CAST()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function :

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(t1.year AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(t1.period AS VARCHAR) + '-1' AS DATE)
```

This will build a string that looks like `{year}-{month}-1`, which will then be parsed as a `DATE` and should give you the first date of the given month/year.

**Using The `DATEFROMPARTS()` Function**

SQL Server 2012 and above actually support a [`DATEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function that will allow you to pass in the various parts (year, month, day) to build a corresponding `DATE` object, with a much easier to read syntax :

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(t1.year,t1.period,1)
```

Additionally, if you needed a `DATETIME` object, you could use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rion - when I try to use DATEFROMPARTS I get error msg 'DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Any ideas on work around?
Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned, this is only available in SQL Server 2012 and above, if you aren't using such a version, you'll need to use the previously suggested approach.

Comment: Thanks - tried old way and get ..
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0-0' to data type int.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It sounds like that is bad data as your year and month would be `0` and `0` respectively, which doesn't seem like a valid, parsable date.

Comment: Ahh I sorted that

Now get ..
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2011-1' to data type int.

T1.period has values 1 to 12 how may I pad this out to 01 to 12

Comment: You shouldn't need to pad the values with zeros as it should parse just fine. Are you making sure to append the trailing `-1` to ensure that your date is read as `{year}-{month}-1`?

Comment: Ooops forgot to put the '' around -1  :)

Getting there - thanks!
How may I format to DD-MM-YYY

Thanks for you assistance Rion!

Comment: changed DATETIME to DATE   YAY!